# Chronic json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) on Raspberry pi 4

Tags: json, linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

i could use some help with an issue I've encountered working on my raspberry pi 4 8gb.
I am working on an app i want to leave to  autorun with lxde-pi on boot, this app is started from the terminal with the following command:

`python3 /home/diego/Desktop/.MVP1.0/entry_point.py`

However i start to get this error at some point after multiple runs:

```
[0:19:01.492998496] [2828]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:297 libcamera v0.0.5+83-bde9b04f
[0:19:01.528111464] [2833]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:437 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx477@1a to Unicam device /dev/media0 and ISP device /dev/media1
[0:19:01.528266843] [2833]  INFO RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1101 Using configuration file '/usr/share/libcamera/pipeline/rpi/vc4/rpi_apps.yaml'
[0:19:01.538365391] [2828]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1033 configuring streams: (0) 640x480-XBGR8888 (1) 1332x990-SBGGR10_CSI2P
[0:19:01.539284259] [2833]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:565 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx477@1a - Selected sensor format: 1332x990-SBGGR10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: 1332x990-pBAA
[0:19:01.567842456] [2828]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1033 configuring streams: (0) 640x480-XBGR8888 (1) 2028x1080-SBGGR12_CSI2P
[0:19:01.568718382] [2833]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:565 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx477@1a - Selected sensor format: 2028x1080-SBGGR12_1X12 - Selected unicam format: 2028x1080-pBCC
[0:19:01.606164870] [2828]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1033 configuring streams: (0) 640x480-XBGR8888 (1) 2028x1520-SBGGR12_CSI2P
[0:19:01.607059591] [2833]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:565 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx477@1a - Selected sensor format: 2028x1520-SBGGR12_1X12 - Selected unicam format: 2028x1520-pBCC
[0:19:01.635910121] [2828]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1033 configuring streams: (0) 640x480-XBGR8888 (1) 4056x3040-SBGGR12_CSI2P
[0:19:01.636472660] [2833]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:565 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx477@1a - Selected sensor format: 4056x3040-SBGGR12_1X12 - Selected unicam format: 4056x3040-pBCC
[0:19:01.688865834] [2828]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1033 configuring streams: (0) 1920x1080-XRGB8888 (1) 2028x1080-SBGGR12_CSI2P
[0:19:01.689407892] [2833]  INFO RPI vc4.cpp:565 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx477@1a - Selected sensor format: 2028x1080-SBGGR12_1X12 - Selected unicam format: 2028x1080-pBCC
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/diego/Desktop/.MVP1.0/Main.py", line 47, in <lambda>
    self.startCameraButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.startCamera())
  File "/home/diego/Desktop/.MVP1.0/Main.py", line 71, in startCamera
    self.qpicameraStart()
  File "/home/diego/Desktop/.MVP1.0/Main.py", line 80, in qpicameraStart
    self.startPicam = PicameraApp(self.picam2, self.qpicamera2, self.systemConfig)
  File "/home/diego/Desktop/.MVP1.0/PicameraApp.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.camera_parameters = CameraParameters(self.picam2, self.systemConfig, True, self, self.qpicamera2)
  File "/home/diego/Desktop/.MVP1.0/CameraParameters.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.load_configuration()
  File "/home/diego/Desktop/.MVP1.0/CameraParameters.py", line 296, in load_configuration
    config = json.load(config_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Aborted
```

I'm not sure what the conditions for it are, i believe it to be related to some other internal non-fatal bug, but the only i can think of is not selecting a file from my file dialogue, I can't be sure that's enough to provoke this though, and i don't think it's something as simple as an x number of boot cycles.

This bug does not go away even after a reboot cycle, but i can still run my app from geany or whatever idle for some reason, if it helps the json file that it gets stuck on is nothing complicated, and i don't think it's possible for it to be read as empty or have some sort of error:

```
{"brightness": 0, "contrast": 100, "saturation": 100, "sharpness": 100, "exposure": 75, "colourgainsR": 0, "colourgainsB": 0, "enable_WB": true, "white_balance": 0, "enable_AE": true, "enable_crosshairs": true, "crosshairs_color": "Red", "crosshairs": {"crosshairs_color_R": true, "crosshairs_color_G": false, "crosshairs_color_B": false}, "vflip_state": 0, "hflip_state": 0}
```

And the code snipet where it throws that error looks as follows:

```
def save_configuration(self):
    config = {
        "brightness": self.brightness_slider.value(),
        "contrast": self.contrast_slider.value(),
        "saturation": self.saturation_slider.value(),
        "sharpness": self.sharpness_slider.value(),
        "exposure": self.exposure_slider.value(),
        "colourgainsR": self.colourgainsR_slider.value(),
        "colourgainsB": self.colourgainsB_slider.value(),
        "enable_WB": self.enable_WB_checkbox.isChecked(),
        "white_balance": self.white_balance_combobox.currentIndex(),
        "enable_AE": self.enable_checkbox.isChecked(),
        "enable_crosshairs": self.enable_crosshairs_checkbox.isChecked(),
        "crosshairs_color": self.lineColor_combobox.currentText(),
        "crosshairs": {
            "crosshairs_color_R": self.red,
            "crosshairs_color_G": self.green,
            "crosshairs_color_B": self.blue,
        },
        "vflip_state": self.vflip_state,
        "hflip_state": self.hflip_state
    }
    with open("config.json", "w") as config_file:
        json.dump(config, config_file)

def load_configuration(self):
    try:
        with open("config.json", "r") as config_file:     ##This is where the error points to, included de rest in case 
            config = json.load(config_file)
        self.brightness_slider.setValue(config["brightness"])
        self.contrast_slider.setValue(config["contrast"])
        self.saturation_slider.setValue(config["saturation"])
        self.sharpness_slider.setValue(config["sharpness"])
        self.exposure_slider.setValue(config["exposure"])
        self.colourgainsR_slider.setValue(config["colourgainsR"])
        self.colourgainsB_slider.setValue(config["colourgainsB"])
        self.enable_WB_checkbox.setChecked(config["enable_WB"])
        self.white_balance_combobox.setCurrentIndex(config["white_balance"])
        self.enable_checkbox.setChecked(config["enable_AE"])
        self.enable_crosshairs_checkbox.setChecked(config["enable_crosshairs"])
        self.lineColor_combobox.setCurrentText(config["crosshairs_color"])
        self.red = config["crosshairs"]["crosshairs_color_R"]
        self.green = config["crosshairs"]["crosshairs_color_G"]
        self.blue = config["crosshairs"]["crosshairs_color_B"]
        self.vflip_state = config["vflip_state"]
        self.hflip_state = config["hflip_state"]
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

Also worth mentioning that the only libraries that i am using are Opencv/cv2, Picam2, and Skimage/Sci-kit image, but these still work and have no errors.

I'm honestly at a loss with this, considering it's more of a chronic error, rather than a bug that shows in the first run and i don't know how to solve it, or prevent it for further iterations, that being said honestly i just need to be able to run my app without encountering this issue, so any workarounds are also appreciated.

Last note, this will also be posted to RPI-Stack.

So far the only real solution has been making a fresh install to my pi, but within whatever attempts i may have in 2-3 hours the error will pop back up again.

Comment: would you upload your config file, when you get the error?

Comment: You should `except` the decode error and log/output what ever `config` is at the time. Given there is a `save_configuration` you may writing and reading at roughly the same time and occasionally find no content in the file when loading. A runtime error would well fit the randomness you observed. Maybe make sure the functions calls do not overlap - lock/semaphore?

Comment: I will look into this, and make sure the functions are not overlapping or ocurring within the same timeframe, will update whatever i discover and see if maybe the config file is at any point empty.